# Ag-grid pivot group count

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using Ag-grid 16.0 with Angular 5.

I want to hide count of pivot group.

```
rowGroup: true,    
cellRenderer:'agGroupCellRenderer',
cellRendererParams: {
    suppressCount: false, // turn off the row count
}
```

suppressCount: false doesn't work for me.

How could I delete the count of pivot group?

Thank you for helping me in advance.

[@pivot group count image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PVGD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
cellRendererParams: {
    suppressCount: true
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077503/how-to-display-different-column-data-as-tool-tip-in-ag-grid... any idea on this?